# How do I avoid extra newlines in firefox copying from a table?

Tags: html, css, firefox, clipboard

I'm trying to render source-code in html+css (no javascript) so that:

- It renders with line-numbers.
- The line-numbers are not copied when the code is selected.
- Internal spaces / tabs / new-lines are preserved.
- The line-numbers are generated automatically.

The solution that I've arrived at uses CSS counters and a table where the leftmost column is a data-psuedo-content (also marked unselectable). It renders correctly in Firefox, Safari and Chrome but there is a problem with copying the text to the clipboard.

- In Chrome and Safari the text copied to the clipboard matches the source.
- In Firefox the lines in the clipboard are double-spaced: there are extra blank lines inbetween each line.

There is a demo [on jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3ak5hnve/3/) that shows the problem. Trying to copy the text to the clipboard in Firefox puts a blank line between every line (i.e. extra newlines).

How can I work around this (using only html+css) ?

```css
.code {
  background-color: none;
  border: none;
  padding: 0;
}

pre.code {
  line-height: 1.6;
  white-space: pre-wrap;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  font-size: 14px;
}

;
pre.code table {
  counter-reset: linenum;
}

pre.code td.lnum:before {
  content: attr(data-psuedo-content) counter(linenum);
}

pre.code td.content {
  font-size: 14px;
  background: #333740;
  color: #ffffff;
  white-space: pre-wrap;
  padding: 3px;
  border-right: solid 2px black;
}

td.lnum {
  background-color: #a7a8aa;
  color: #000000;
  border-right: 2px solid black;
  border-top: 1px solid black;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  border-left: none;
  font-size: 12px;
}

pre.code tr {
  counter-increment: linenum;
}

.lnum {
  -moz-user-select: none;
  webkit-user-select: none;
  ms-user-select: none;
}
```

```html
<pre class="code">
  <table style="width: 100%;border-collapse: collapse">
    <tr><td class="lnum"></td><td class="content">#include &lt;stdint.h&gt;</td></tr>
    <tr><td class="lnum"></td><td class="content">#include &lt;stdbool.h&gt;</td></tr>
    <tr><td class="lnum"></td><td class="content"></td></tr>
    <tr><td class="lnum"></td><td class="content">/*-</td></tr>
    <tr><td class="lnum"></td><td class="content"> | Support for x86 operations that are not exposed natively in C. Each of these</td></tr>
    <tr><td class="lnum"></td><td class="content"> | is a fragment of inline-assembly (a way of injecting assembly code into the</td></tr>
    <tr><td class="lnum"></td><td class="content"> | compiled program). Each one is wrapped in an inline procedure so that the </td></tr>
  </table>
</pre>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

don't add this code

```
.lnum { 
      -moz-user-select: none;
      webkit-user-select: none;
      ms-user-select: none;
    }
```

Comment: That partly solves it: the extra lines are gone when pasting the clipboard, but now a hard-tab character starts every line but the first.

Comment: Found a work-around for the tabs: ctrl-drag in Firefox selects the table cells in an alternative way and then when pasted there are no tabs for the cells. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

I used JavaScript to hook the copy event:

```
const source = document.querySelector('pre.code');

source.addEventListener('copy', (event) => {
    const selection = document.getSelection();
    event.clipboardData.setData('text/plain', selection.toString());
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: The accepted answer above works without javascript.

Answer (score 0):

I found that `user-select: text` was inadequate because it also copied a tab character `\t` or newline `\n` when triple-clicking a table cell (depending on which cell you click. The last cell includes `\n`, and other cells include `\t`).

My solution is to use JS to override the `'copy'` event, with these considerations:

- Do not copy a trailing `\r` or `\n`.
- Copy only plain text, not formatted text.
- Grab the text from `innerText` to mimic normal UA text selection, if there are line breaks, etc.
- Still allow partial text selection in the column (only triple-click selects everything, or if the user manually selects all of the text).

This implementation is in React:

```tsx
export function TripleClickable ({
    children,
}: {
    children: string;
}) {
    const [el, setEl] = useState<HTMLElement | null>(null);
    useEffect(() => {
        if (!el) return;
        el.addEventListener('copy', (event) => {
            if (!event.clipboardData) return;
            const selection = document.getSelection();
            if (!selection) return;
            // Stop if the full text is not selected.
            if (
                // Catch if the selection isn't from the beginning.
                selection.anchorOffset !== 0 ||
                // Catch if the selection isn't to the end. (If so, then focusNode would be in a different element.)
                (selection.focusNode && selection.focusNode.parentElement === el)
            ) return;
            const text = el.innerText;
            event.clipboardData.setData('text/plain', text);
            event.preventDefault();
        });
    }, [el]);
    return (
        <span ref={setEl}>
            {String(children) /* to prevent unexpected usage */}
        </span>
    );
}
```